# Digitize textbook

Tags: video-editing, ocr, scanning, pictures, digitization

How can I digitize my physics textbook?  It's huge and I don't want to cut the spine.

I saw a picture of this: [Ion Audio](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Ion+Audio+-+Book+Saver+e-Reader+Conversion+Book+Scanner/2658262.p?id=1218343870346&skuId=2658262&cmp=RMX&ref=06&loc=01&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=2658262)

[image]

I want to know what's most important when making my own.  I have a digital camera, and I have lights.  I was thinking of making a movie of me flipping each page, then just using OCR software (maybe even Acrobat) to get all the words, tables and diagrams.

**My questions:**

1. Is Acrobat the program of choice once I have the pictures?
2. What (kind of) software can recognize when I flip each page (so each frame can be removed and analyzed by Acrobat-like software).  Does software like this exist?  Should I just use a stopwatch program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://www.diybookscanner.org/news/) would probably be a good start, since its got both hardware and software suggestions. I suspect using a pair of canons + CHDK (since they have simple, DIYable remote triggers+ setting them to to click based off the same trigger as the page turning part of the hardware would be simplest, and there's a few FOSS software suggestions there such as Bindery, DJVUBind, and PDFmaker.

I hate posting links alone, but this is just too complex a project to fit into a single answer

Comment: +1 for good answer.  Isn't there some way I could use a video though (I just think it'd be sooo much easier)